# How can I change my context root in WebWork?

Tags: jsp, root, webwork

I am currently working on a huge web application consisting of JSPs. Also I use WebWork framework.

Until now the context root of my application was "/".  Now I want to change that to "nstat".

How should I handle the relative and absolute calls from my JSPs?

Answer (score 0):

For jsps you can use the `<c:url/>` tag to build proper relative urls. Webwork has a similir custom tag named `<ww:url/>`.

```
<c:url val="somepath/some.jsp"/>
```

Will be translated to "/nstat/somepath/some.jsp". If you set the var attribute you can use the url later on in your jsp using the `${}` notation.

Comment: please explain in detail...
Is there any other way other then using request.getContextpath()...